# How to write script for vs.net setup?

Tags: c#

I have an exe, now I want to deploy this so I have written setup in vs.net. And i have added two check boxes, " Launch the application " and " Set as startup " , but my question is how do I handle the these two events ? As for as i know i need to write the Script to validate and execute according to the input given by the user for these two actions.

Can some one tell me whether i am right or wrong?, if I am right then which script is the easier one? and please let me know the steps to accomplish my task.

Thanks in advance,
Ravi Naik.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Well my first question to you is - Why are you using VS.Net setup? It is not the friendliest setup on the planet, and nor it is the most efficient. Ask yourself, how many professional programs use VS.Net setup?

Now my advice to you - Use Innosetup. With very slight modifications to the standard script it supports .Net framework. It's compact, very lightweight, very efficient and very-very tested.

There will be a little investment required in learning how it works (cause it don't have no fancy GUI), but once you've put in a couple of weekends you'll never want to go back to anything else.

Oh, and did I tell you that it has excellent scripting capabilities in a Pascal like language and that you can get ready sample code for practically everything?

Comment: Well, the reason I am using the VS setup is that you can easily configure everything through a simple GUI interface, and you only need a couple of minutes to get to know the basics on how to do a simple setup (not a 2-week seminar...). 
Oh, and did I tell you that VS automatically creates most of what you need in the setup based on the application project(s) you are creating the setup for...? (at least if your project to deploy is standard .NET)

Comment: Hi awe, also must tell you the fact that 1. VS made setup is slower than everything else in exisence. 2. It will have an inordinate rate of failure. 3. Innosetup has a GUI (from a third party, free). 4. Since you are a programmer, seriously pursuing a career, it is worth it to know about packaging your software properly even if it takes 2 weeks.